# assembler addressing in AT&T

Tags: assembly

Can anyone help me understanding this command:

```
mov %esp,%edi

lea 0x10(%edi),%esi
```

first I load the address of `esp` to `edi`.
then I load the value of `edi+10`, that means the address of `esp+10` to `esi`.
But what does that mean for the stack? If I do a push, I write 4 byte on the stack, right? And if I jump 10 Byte back on my stack, where is this point?

```
|______|         # here?
|______|
|______|
|______|
|______|
|______|
|______|
|___*__|         # or at the position of the star?
|______|         # 4 Byte
|______|         # also 4 Byte long...
|______|   <---%edi
```

Comment: `0x10 == 16` for the record...

Comment: and 16/4 is 4 4-byte words....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on x86, and not x64, right? I'm going to assume this.

**"What does this mean to the stack?"**

```
mov %esp,%edi
lea 0x10(%edi),%esi
```

This code will have no effect on your stack operations (`push`, `pop`, ect). That's because stack operations work on the `esp` register as your stack pointer. The above code doesn't change `esp`, so as far as the stack's concerned, nothing is changed.

**"If I do a push, I write 4 bytes on the stack, right?":**

Not necessarily. x86 supports push operations on 16-bit and 32-bit operands, so the amount of bytes you write to the stack depends on the size of what you're pushing. For example:

```
push %ax  ; will push 2 bytes on the stack (sizeof(ax) == 2)
push %eax ; will push 4 bytes on the stack (sizeof(eax) == 4)
```

Note that push also subtracts `esp` by `sizeof(op1)`.

**"And if I jump 10 bytes back on my stack, where is this point?"**

The `lea` command on the `esi` will not change the stack pointer. So,

```
nop                   ; 10 points back on the stack here
mov %esp,%edi       
lea 0x10(%edi),%esi
nop                   ; will be the exact same location as here.
                      ; relative to esi, this location is (esi - 26)
```